# How can I counteract the effects of the Ensanguined Shield?

Tags: final-fantasy-12

I've got an Ensanguined Shield. It's very powerful, but puts the negative status effects of Poison, Slow and Sap on a character when it's equipped.

How can I most effectively manage these negative effects on my character?

Is there any way to "cure' this shield?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had good results using this shield with a careful selection of buffs and equipment.

A ribbon won't overcome the status effects, but Haste will negate Slow, and Regen will negate Sap and Poison to a degree. I've equipped a character with the Ensanguined Shield, a Renewing Morion (for Regen), and a Maximillian (for overall stats) and a Battle Harness (for automatic counters).  I've also set Gambits to constantly cast Decoy, Bubble and Haste (and several healing spells) on the character with the Ensanguined Shield, and unlocked the Martyr license for that character.

The Decoy / Ensanguined Shield / Battle Harness combo works great - this character is pretty much the only one ever targeted by enemies and dodges most attacks; and they counter if they are hit.  Hermes Sandles could be equipped for the Haste, if you prefer to save a Gambit slot. (Casting Mirror on this character is a bad idea unless you plan to heal via Items.)

There is no way to fix this shield.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get rid of these status effects; even equipping a Ribbon won't do the trick.  The best you can do is to keep Haste and Regen on the character in question to obviate the Slow and Sap/Poison.  (In my opinion, it's probably not worth it - I can think of very few situations where you *absolutely need* such high levels of Evasion, and certainly very few worth skipping being Hasted over!  It may be useful in a few situations with Decoy on that character, though.)